# unexpected WITH ROLLUP behavior

Tags: mysql

I do WITH ROLLUP on a particular query and get this back as the result:

```
sex       avgAge
Female    54
Male      49
Male      52
```

My question is...  why does the third column have Male in it? Shouldn't it have NULL?

The query:

```
SELECT sex, COUNT(1) AS avgAge
FROM people
GROUP BY IFNULL(sex,'')
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely that the expression in the `GROUP BY` clause does not match the column name in the SELECT list.

Excerpted from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html

<snip>

The NULL indicators in each super-aggregate row are produced when the row is sent to the client. The server looks at the columns named in the GROUP BY clause following the leftmost one that has changed value. For any column in the result set with a name that is a lexical match to any of those names, its value is set to NULL. (If you specify grouping columns by column number, the server identifies which columns to set to NULL by number.)

</snip>

So, the short answer is, there isn't a "lexical match" between the expression in the GROUP BY clause and the name of the column in the resultset, so the value of that column in the super-aggregate row is not getting set to NULL.

---

We also note that the query you provide isn't the one producing that result set. We notice that the alias `avgAge` is not assigned to the second column, and the value in the rollup row appears to be the result of an `AVG` aggregate, rather than a `COUNT` aggregate.  For a `COUNT` aggregate, we'd expect the rollup value to be 103.

---

To get a NULL in the first column of that rollup ("super-aggregate") row, you'd need something like this:

```
SELECT t.sex, COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM people t
 GROUP BY t.sex
  WITH ROLLUP
```

If you want to handle NULL value like empty string, then something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t.sex,'') AS sex, COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM people t
 GROUP BY sex
  WITH ROLLUP
```

Note that the name in the GROUP BY references the alias assigned to the expression in the SELECT list, rather than a column in the table.